# Editing custom visual code, packaging pbiviz, visualizating in PBI Desktop

Tags: visual-studio, powerbi, powerbi-custom-visuals, pbiviz

I downloaded Power BI custom visual code from GitHub. In Visual Studio I installed the PBIViz CLI Control extension.
The custom visual is a calendar in which I'm trying to make some alterations to spelling mostly. I'm not very familiar to Visual Studio or coding but I do understand some bits of the code.

This is how I started.
First in VS terminal commanded pbiviz start.

I manually looked for the words and abbreviations in the code that I want to change e.g. in .tmp\drop\pbiviz.json, \src\helpers\helpers.ts and \capabilities.json. I'm not sure which of all the files I need to modify or is this a correct way at all. There's a possibility that I miss some files also.
I pressed the ctrl+s after each change.

Third I commanded pbiviz package. This step works and a pbiviz is created and I'm able to import it to PBI Desktop. But when I'm using the calendar no changes occur, the words and abbreviations are the same as in the original code.

If I check again the VS code some changes are there but some are changed back to the original words.

Can anyone help on how to implement the changes to the code?

Comment: You need to share your code also or bits of it like where you are making changes to alter the text in appearance. The main part is, please share how your visual.ts file looks like.

Comment: Probably, you used old GUID of visual. If visual published in Appsource, Power BI downloads the visual from CDN, not matter which version you use. Change GUID in pbiviz.json and create package again. After that Power BI start use your package instead the visual from CDN, when you import visual package in Power BI Desktop